# How to access a two-dimensional array in a structure using a structure pointer in a function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm new here, so forgive my mistakes. I'm clearly not familiarized with pointers nor structure, in general, I'm not the best programmer either. But anyways, I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

I'm trying to allocate space for the "2-d array [tag]" variable in my structure in "func." I can't seem to get any of the assignments to work, due the bad referencing of "tag." Here's the errors being produced:

```
    prog.c: In function ‘func’:
    prog.c:33: error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
    prog.c:38: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
    prog.c:39: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

Thanks in advance!

```
    // prog.c
    struct Str
    {
        unsigned int s;
        unsigned int e;
        unsigned long int tag;
    };


    void func(struct Str *str)
    {
        str->tag = malloc(str->s * sizeof(unsigned long int *)); // 33 str->tag error

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < str->s; i++)
        {
            str->tag[i] = malloc(str->e * sizeof(unsigned long int)); // 38 str->tag[i] error
            memset(str->tag[i], -1, str->e * sizeof(unsigned long int)); // 39 str->tag[i] error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your `tag` a double pointer:

```
struct Str
{
    unsigned int s;
    unsigned int e;
    unsigned long int** tag;
};
```

Comment: Wow! That was an easy fix. Thank you! Also, Am I referencing "tag" the correct way? Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: I think that the rest is okay, I don't see anything wrong.